# Change Last 2 Numbers in Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Trying to create a new column "FiscalQrtr" that uses "Date" column in a case when, but am unable to figure it out so I went the update approach and am receiving an error message that states

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%02' to data
> type int".

The date column I believe is `YYYYMM`, so an example result would be: if Date = 200103 then FiscalQrtr = 200101

Update code looks like this:

```
select * 
into #claims1 
FROM #claims 

update #claims1
set Date = left(Date, len(Date)-2) + '01'
where Date in ('%01','%02','%03');
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated

Comment: `TxnFiscalPeriod` is clearly an `int`, so the error is very clear here.

Comment: `where TxnFiscalPeriod % 100 BETWEEN 1 AND 3`

Comment: Still unsure how to accomplish the task at hand...need to use Date (column has a series of YYYYMMs ) to convert the last 2 characters to the correct fiscal quarter.

Comment: `select * into #claims1 FROM #claims ` This is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do all 4 quarters at once?

```
UPDATE #claims1
SET Date = LEFT(Date, 4) + '0' + RTRIM((RIGHT(Date,2)-1)/3+1);
```

If you don't like the unintuitive `-1/3+1` math, you can write something that is much clearer in intent:

```
UPDATE #claims1 SET Date = LEFT(Date, 4) + '0' +
  RTRIM(DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(Date,4), RIGHT(Date,2), 1)));
```

If you just want to handle Q1 for some reason, ok, just add:

```
WHERE RIGHT(RTRIM(Date),1) < 4;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e29fe5962a8d2c30ac32a62cc8ee3de7)

Answer (score 1):

If the `Date` column is actually a 6 digit integer, representing `YYYYMM`, **you can use a bit of arithmetic for this:**

```
update #claims1
set Date = (Date / 100 * 100) + 1
where Date % 100 <= 3;
```

`(Date / 100 * 100)` truncates it, then you just add 1

You can also do all four quarters at once

```
update #claims1
set Date = (Date / 100 * 100) + (Date % 100 / 4 * 3 + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data type of your column Date is `INT` and an `INT` data type cannot be used with `LIKE`. So instead, convert the Column to `VARCHAR` and perform the update. Like this

```
update #claims1
set Date = left(CAST(Date AS VARCHAR(20)), len(CAST(Date AS VARCHAR(20))-2)) + '01'
where RIGHT(CAST(Date AS VARCHAR(20)),2) in ('01','02','03');
```

Comment: Getting an "incorrect syntax near where"

Comment: @2020db9, a parenthesis was missing. updated now